# is it possible to avoid windows update?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, update, nokia-lumia-730

The space in my lumia 730 is only 8gb out of which 6 is used by the system and microsoft apps that can't be moved. Microsoft keep pushing updates that fills the system memory making it inoperable and slow.

Is there is a way or a registry tweak through which i can disable the windows update automatically and do it manually whenever i want ?

Comment: I had been in a similar situation in the past and I eventually ended up hard-resettibg my phone and letting the restore feature get my phone back into a decent state once I had installed the update. It's a pain, but at least you aren't letting you yourself be exposed to unpatched security issues.
Does the 730 have an SD Card slot? That might provide an alternative avenue.

Comment: @ShafiqJetha Yes it has a microSD with 64gb but i don;t know how to download updates on SD card, is that even possible ?

Comment: You should be able to move some of the applications to the SD Card, and that might free up enough space on the device's main memory to allow you to download the update.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I suppose you could. You can turn this off in **Privacy>>Background Apps>>phone update** if you flick off phone update you shouldn't receive anymore updates automatically!

Comment: It's like that only, still when i connect to my WiFi it will start downloading